# Populate a cell if a condition is met - in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to write a quick Google Sheets code that allows me to do the following:
In a cell (under the chart shown), if the value in the *Diff.* column is greater than 0 (the red cells), I want to populate the cells with the item from the "Part Description" column.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would return the part description in column A if either the value of Diff in column F or I was greater than 0.

```
=IF(F2>0,A2,(IF(I2>0,A2,)))
```

Then to create a list of the unique results without blanks.

`=UNIQUE(J1:J)`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Now, if I drag the formula down, and the logical returns false.  How could I remove the blank cells and simply keep the ones that returned the Part Description cell value?

Comment: @Nick answer amended

Comment: Hi Tom - Thanks a lot!